# Какие есть актуальные ресурсы по поиску фишинговых и мошеннических доменов?

Tags: безопасность

Специалисты threat intelligence подскажите, пожалуйста, какие нибудь ресурсы, на которых можно искать фишинговые домены, мошеннические сайты, списки черных ip адресов, на которых часто регистрируют фишинговые домены. Подойдут всякого рода форумы, платформы, отдельные сайты и т. д, короче какие либо угодно источники с актуальной информацией, желательно которые бы обновлялись каждый день ну или чуть реже. Так же сайты, где бесплатно можно выгрузить зарегистрированные фишинговые домены (или просто домены), ресурсы с бесплатными фидами. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

[PhishTank](https://phishtank.org/) – онлайн-сервис, который предоставляет информацию о фишинговых сайтах и других вредоносных веб-сайтах.

[URLhaus](https://urlhaus.abuse.ch/) – база данных, которая отслеживает и предоставляет информацию о фишинговых сайтах и других вредоносных веб-сайтах. Есть API

[Malware Domain List](https://www.malwaredomainlist.com/) - название само говорит о контенте сайта

Comment: Это самые основные и популярные. Можно поискать еще, но не думаю что там будут обновления каждый день как вам требуется